# How to remove entire sentence if it contains string? PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to clean up a large text using PHP by removing certain phrases which relate to other texts which I do not have. These phrases are typically between two html tags like `<i>this</i>` but I would like to remove only those which containing a keyword, which is "See also".

Is there a way to do this with **preg_replace** ?

Given the following input:

```
<h1>this is a header</h1>
<i>See also staying safe in Taiwan</i>
<p>Some long text here</p>
<i>Some more text over here</i>
<p>Some more text <i>here</i></p>
```

How can I remove the entire phrase containing the string "**See also**". Expected output:

```
<h1>this is a header</h1>
<p>Some long text here</p>
<i>Some more text over here</i>
<p>Some more text <i>here</i></p>
```

The thing to look out for is "See also".

Thank you!

Comment: use regex and `preg_replace`

Comment: You can use DOMDocument and split it into the tags and then remove any that contains the text you are after.

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt

Comment: @FelippeDuarte how would i achieve this with pre_replace?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte DON'T USE REGEX FOR THAT! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<i>(See also)([^<]*)<\/i>/i",'', $text);
```